# How to secure POSTs made by limiting where they are sent from

Tags: php, flash, post, actionscript

Okay firstly I have a question that question being - Can people view what posts are being sent? For example, in a flash game when a POST is made to a web page, is there any way a user can view that POST's data?

If they can then my original idea of posting a password wouldn't work. But I didn't think a password would be that efficient anyway.

So.. what's the best way to make it so source A can only post to source B.

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Who do you mean by "people" exactly - the user making the request? Everyone else? Why do you need this restriction, can you elaborate?

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit on your specific situation and what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: You cannot prevent, in any way/shape/form, the user from inspecting what their browser is doing. To see how easy it is to view your flash communications, install HTTPFox and/or Firebug and you can view EVERYTHING. ssl does not protect this,b ecause ssl only applies to the wire communications.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] ***is there any way a user can view that POST's data?***

Yes. The user can inspect what is sent from his computer.

If you for instance have a game and want to submit some high score, then there is basically no way to make sure that the user doesn't perform hand-crafted posts with arbitrary score.

> ***So.. what's the best way to make it so source A can only post to source B.***

Not sure what you mean by this, but if you want to make sure that only posts from a specific client are processed by the server, then I believe you should simply establish a session using for instance cookies.

---

If you're facing the scenario where you have to for instance submit a highscore you have a few options:

- You could apply some cipher on the data being sent. This won't stop any one trying to hack the game and submit arbitrary scores since he can always look at the code, and figure out how to create these cipher texts himself. You can make this process harder by obfuscating the code, but there's basically no way to be 100% secure.
- You can monitor every action in the game and verify that the final score is the result of a valid game-play on the server. The user would then have to hand-craft a complete legal game play in order to fake a score.
- You can do the above, but *record* all actions in the game, and do a "post-game check" on the server side and verify that the final score is the result of a valid game.

---

You say it's very critical. In that case you're either out of luck, or there is some application specific feature you can exploit to work around it.

Comment: True, but what about SSL though? What if the Flash applet establishes a SSL connection to the server? It becomes a lot harder then

Comment: Are you sure plugins like Firebug wouldn't pick it up?

Comment: @aiiobe not if it's the plugin itself establishing the connection. (You can still fetch unencrypted POSTs using a packet sniffer though, so in essence, you're right)

Comment: oh dear! What am I going to do? :(

Comment: @JordanRichards, are you facing the "submit high score" scenario?

Comment: Not facing it RIGHT NOW. But preparing for it yeah D:

Comment: Depends on how critical the application is. Let me update my answer.